# Excluded url from Google Analytics still appearing in data

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to permanently filter our some data from my Google analytics results so a sub URL plus anything following it is excluded. For example:

```
/examplesuburl/index.html  
/examplesuburl/about-us/index.html  
/examplesubsurl/contact-us/index.html
```

I've tried going to **Admin > View > Filters** and then setting up a filter that has the following parameters:

Filter type: Exclude, traffic to the subdirectories, that contain

```
Sub-directory: /examplesubdirectory/
```

When I validate this I can see it pulls up the data I want to exclude but then when I go to **Behaviour > Site Content > All pages** the data is still there.

Have I set up this filter wrong? Or is there a more effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

filters are not retroactive and will not remove historical data already reported within a View, only going forward from the time the filter is applied.

Once you apply a filter it can take 24-48hrs to start to see the difference within the View's standard reports, if you adjust the date range at the upper right to the day after you applied the filter, up to and including the current day's date, then you should be able to see the result of the filtered data.